# Center column takes twice the space - css layout

Tags: html, css

In my application i need to create a layout like the image below.i tried using flex it doesn't seems to work,guys help me out on how to achieve this layout using flexbox css. In the first row it should be four divs and second row it be three div's

[image]

```css
body{
  background-color:#f5f6fa;
}
.parent{
  margin:20px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child{
  flex: 1 0 21%; 
    margin: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" ></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to stick with Flexbox and not Grid?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to the flexbox then try these codes. (But grid would be more appropriate)

```
  <div class="parent flex-container align-items-stretch">
      <div class="child" style="flex-grow: 1">1</div>
      <div class="child" style="flex-grow: 1">2</div>
      <div class="child" style="flex-grow: 1">3</div>
      <div class="child" style="flex-grow: 1">4</div>
      <div class="child" style="flex-grow: 1">5</div>
      <div class="child" style="flex-grow: 12">6</div>
      <div class="child" style="flex-grow: 1">7</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use `display:grid;` instead of `flexbox`.

Here is an example how you can do this easily.

`grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);` creates 4 columns, and repeats them until the max of 4 is achieved.

Selecting the sixth child from the `.child` class and giving him `grid-column:span 2;`, makes him span across two columns.

`grid-gap:20px;` sets the space between all grid columns.

```css
body{
  background-color:#f5f6fa;
}
.parent{
  margin:20px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap:20px;
}
.child{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.child:nth-child(6){
  grid-column:span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" ></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The flex-basis CSS property sets the initial main size of a flex item. It sets the size of the content box unless otherwise set with box-sizing.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

```css
body{
  background-color:#f5f6fa;
}
.parent{
  margin:20px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 
}
.child{
  flex: 1 0 21%; 
    margin: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.bigger{
  flex-basis: 46%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" >1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child bigger">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
</div
```